# Rebasing a feature branch

Tags: git

We need insight at work regarding the best method to manage branching and rebasing of feature branches for our software. We have:

- development on main repository
- feature-A on main repository

and then we have

- feature-A-dev-xyz on each dev's repository

When we have changes to development, should we merge development into feature-A and risk sending conflicts to all devs rebasing the feature branch, or should we rebase feature-A off development and then live the same conflicts for everyone on their machine again (if any)...

What is the best approach, is there another one, thanks!

Comment: I would always avoid rebasing branches that other people are actively using. That means only rebasing personal branches, or only rebasing a feature branch immediately before merging it into development. This avoids anyone giving anybody else conflicts.

Comment: Agreed. For a feature branch used by more than one person, I wouldn't rebase at all. A straight-line history isn't mandatory.

Comment: This was one solution, branch off development and hold off rebasing until the end when we are ready to merge into development, then, we rebase off development, but no one rebase from dev until then unless absolutely necessary...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're misusing feature branches. Each developer should not have their own branch of each feature branch. It is, as you've discovered, overly complicated. This is probably because your features are too big.

Instead, there should be *one* feature branch for each feature. Features should be small enough that feature branches are fairly short lived and don't need further branching for long lived developer experiments. When a feature is done, the branch is not reused and is deleted.

The work of individual developers on a feature is already isolated by their local repository. Habitual pushes should be discouraged, developers should only push their changes to the feature branch when their work is ready to be shared.

---

As a rule of thumb, any branch which is shared (ie. pushed) should not be rebased or else it will cause problems for everyone downstream. For simplicity you should use `merge` to update your shared feature branches. However, when the feature is ready to be merged then you can use rebase to clean up the history.

There are, of course, exceptions. If all the developers are comfortable with rebasing then shared branches can be rebased. It's generally polite to send out a message letting everyone know a rebase has happened, so they can expect the inevitable `pull` error.

Comment: Yeah, i agree on short lived branches, i wish i could do it like that and merge back every issue from JIRA into the dev branch, but we are developping a new app that sometimes requires lots of changes so we don't release to prod something unfinished. Our remote feature branches are mapped to the EPICS in JIRA and each dev branch are mapped to JIRA issues.

Comment: One of the solution we came to as we discussed was to branch on upstream to create the feature branch from dev and then each dev, as they create issues create their own issue based branch to be deleted once merged into the feature branch and hold off on rebasing the feature branch unless ABSOLUTELY necessary. Then when the feature is finished, we rebase feature from dev on upstream, fix the conflicts, test and merge. What do you think? Is that the best approach?

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin I think you need to ask another question with all that detail in it.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the github workflow than should satisfy your needs...

2 Good sources on the subject:

https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/

And an advice: you should not rebase a branch published/shared onto which developers are working, except perhaps, just before merging it,  to simplify the history...

Comment: Could you provide a link and explanation?

Comment: Sorry, didn't had time to add link in the first answer.  Now it's done ;-)